# How to use javascript using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Scenario:

I created a filtering using `IF ELSE` where when the user click BOX A AND BOX B... Then assuming the BOX A is already full, after the user hit the "SAVE BUTTON", a confirmation message will display saying that... *"The Box you chosen is already full. Do you want to save the other items?"*

Here's my Code:

```
<?php
//else if......
    else if($box== "BOX A" && $row[item]  == "100")
    {

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "var r=confirm('The Box you chosen is already full. Do you want to save the other items?')";
        echo "if (r==true){";
        echo "alert('You pressed OK!')}";
        echo "else{";
        echo "alert('You pressed Cancel!')}";
        echo "</script>";

    }
?>
```

I have a problem with the code and when I try to trace it using `echo "enter here";`
its always stop after the program read this code

```
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
```

Then it will jump it in here:

```
 echo "</script>";
```

RESULT:

its not displaying the pop up message ... So all I need is to display the pop up message and I dont know why, why its not displaying... There is no button involve for the displaying of confirmation message...It will just pass by in if else and then it will prompt up if the user wants to continue the saving if one of the box is already full if not he/she will press the cancel...

NOTE:
I'm only a beginner for PHP and Javascript..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to start with a basic tutorial on PHP.

Comment: Remove the `<?php` and `?>` as you're already using PHP

Comment: @GroovyCarrot...Sorry I already revised my code...I just missed copied it....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because you start a new `<?` / `<?php` tag inside another

```
else if($box== "BOX A" && $row[item]  == "100")
{
    <?php
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "var r=confirm('The Box you chosen is already full. Do you want to save the other items?')";
    echo "if (r==true){";
    echo "alert('You pressed OK!')}";
    echo "else{";
    echo "alert('You pressed Cancel!')}";
    echo "</script>";
    ?>
}
```

should be

```
else if($box== "BOX A" && $row[item]  == "100")
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "var r=confirm('The Box you chosen is already full. Do you want to save the other items?')";
    echo "if (r==true){";
    echo "alert('You pressed OK!')}";
    echo "else{";
    echo "alert('You pressed Cancel!')}";
    echo "</script>";
}
```

But personally I think

```
    else if($box== "BOX A" && $row[item]  == "100")
    {
?>
<script>
var r=confirm('The Box you chosen is already full. Do you want to save the other items?')";
if (r==true) {
    alert('You pressed OK!');
} else {
    alert('You pressed Cancel!');
}
</script>
<?
    }
```

is much cleaner and more readable. Keep javascript out of PHP, dont echo it out, if you can avoid it. It can be hard to survey in 6 months.

Comment: @davidkonrad...I tried that already, but I have an error..."Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in" when I tried to do the same you did....

Comment: Gr8! I couldnt image the above wouldnt work :) guess you suddenly had an extra <? or something like that.

Comment: @davidkonrad...der is no extra, its like that I chopped everything using php tag...thanks

Answer (score 3):

Or you can do something like this.

```
    <?php
    //some PHP code
    if($box== "BOX A" && $row[item]== 100)
    {
    ?>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
        var r=confirm('The Box you chosen is already full. Do you want to save the other items?');
        if (r==true){
        alert('You pressed OK!')}
        else{
        alert('You pressed Cancel!')}
        </script>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Yes, defently much better inmo

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you have put a php tag and an if statement before this line

```
else if($box== "BOX A" && $row[item]  == "100")
```

The fact is that you don't need to open another php tag. You are already writing in php so you don't need to specify it again since it will cause your code to fail. You could write something like this instead.

```
else if($box == "BOX A" && $row[item] == "100")
{ ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var r=confirm('The Box you chosen is already full. Do you want to save the other items?');
    if (r==true)
        alert('You pressed OK!');
    else
        alert('You pressed Cancel!');
    </script>
  <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = <<<MY_MARKER
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Hello World!");
</script>
MY_MARKER;
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is basically because when you're echo'ing your javascript you're forgetting that the `;` character still needs to proceed JS lines:

```
<?php
//else if......
    else if($box== "BOX A" && $row[item]  == "100")
    {

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                var r = confirm('The Box you chosen is already full. Do you want to save the other items?'); // <- this was missing
                if (r == true){
                    alert('You pressed OK!');
                }
                else{
                    alert('You pressed Cancel!');
                }
                </script>";

    }
?>
```

Little trick I use is that PHP echo allows new lines without breaking so you can always just echo a block of code and look over it easier