# Change the login button to logout button when user is logged in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, authentication

I have read these links:

- [How to change login and logout links dynamically in HTML page in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721614/how-to-change-login-and-logout-links-dynamically-in-html-page-in-php)
- [How to use javascript using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068311/how-to-use-javascript-using-php)

I have a question which is a little specific. I have a `minimallogin` folder which contains all the register and login PHP code. In this folder, I have `index.php` which contains this following code:

```
<?php
// checking for minimum PHP version
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7', '<')) {
    exit("Sorry, Simple PHP Login does not run on a PHP version smaller than 5.3.7 !");
} else if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '<')) {
    // if you are using PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4 you have to include the password_api_compatibility_library.php
    // (this library adds the PHP 5.5 password hashing functions to older versions of PHP)
    require_once("libraries/password_compatibility_library.php");
}

// include the configs / constants for the database connection
require_once("config/db.php");

// load the login class
require_once("classes/Login.php");

$login = new Login();

// ... ask if we are logged in here:
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {

    //after logged in


} else {

    //after logged out
}
?>
```

I tried the following two things, but either got stuck somewhere or couldn't get it to work whatsoever:

1) **First method** (with Javascript) I have given the ID `registerloginarea` (in HTML) to the area where I want to change my login button with my logout link. I have tried a lot of things. I am just learning Javascript and hence I tried writing a function like this:

```
function loggedin(){
    document.getElementById("registerloginarea").innerHTML="logged in";
}
```

But I really have no idea how I am going to implement this function into my `index.php` (into after logged in part).

**Note:** Also I don't want to output "logged in". I want output as "Hey, [name].Logout" in place of the login button once the user is logged in for which the code is:

```
Hey, $_SESSION['user_name']
<a href="index.php?logout">Logout</a>"
```

2) Alternatively, I also did this:

```
<ul id="registerloginarea" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-btn">
                <?php
                include("/minimallogin/index.php");

                $login = new Login();

                // ... ask if we are logged in here:
                if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {
                    // the user is logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
                    // for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are logged in" view.
                    echo $_SESSION['user_name'];
                    echo "<a href=\"index.php?logout\">Logout</a>";



                } else {
                    // the user is not logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
                    // for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are not logged in" view.
                    include("/var/www/html/C-CubeClub/includes/registerloginarea.php");
                }
                ?>
           </ul>
```

The half part before the `$login...` is included in the `minimallogin/index.php`.
But still when I sign in it parses the `minimallogin/index.php` (because I have included it as `<form action="minimallogin/index.php">` in my form.
How do you suggest I get this thing working. It may have a very simple answer but pardon me.